# Paypal subscription intergration

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am currently trying to integrate paypal into my CMS for subscription, but I can't find anything useful after adding the paypal button to my site. Can anyone recommend where I can go from here or a guide I can use?

Paypals documentation is absolutely rubbish

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="2354H7J8CK88E">
<table style="margin:0 auto 15px;">
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Account Types">Account Types</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="Basic">Basic : &pound;14.99 GBP - monthly</option>
    <option value="Plus">Plus : &pound;29.99 GBP - monthly</option>
    <option value="Pro">Pro : &pound;44.99 GBP - monthly</option>
    <option value="Business">Business : &pound;59.99 GBP - monthly</option>
    <option value="Unlimited">Unlimited : &pound;79.99 GBP - monthly</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input name="companyid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo getCompanyID(); ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a PayPal 'sandbox' account. And look at the docs here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/ . There are code samples available for IPN (Instant Payment Notification).

Using the sandbox is great, since you can test your processes without spending any real money. (Although you will spend 'real time'.)>

There are also several tutorials; one is here http://www.codexworld.com/paypal-standard-payment-gateway-integration-php/ .

Good luck!